# XSL-FO processor for PHP : transform XML to PDF

Tags: php, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am looking for a PHP XSL-FO processor.

What I need is an alternative to [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) (in the Java world), in order to convert an XML document to PDF, but I need to execute it in a PHP environment without Java support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP XSL extension doesn’t support XSL-FO so a Java Bridge is about your only option I think